# Three sigma confidence interval for rayleigh distributed quantity

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Please consider a one dimensional measurement device, which can measure a position in $x$ direction and is specified to have a precision of $3\sigma(x) < thr$, where $thr$ is a threshold value, for example a few nanometer. That means 99,73% of the measurements have an error $|\Delta x|$ of less than $thr$.

Now I combine two of these devices to measure an $(x,y)$ position. How can I write the specification for $r=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$ to indicate that 99,73% of the measurement errors $r$ are lower than $thr$?

I understand that when $\Delta x$ is normal distributed, then $r$ is Rayleigh distributed. I tried a spec like $\bar{r}+3\sigma(r) <  thr$, but the deviation is quite high.

Comment: The square of a [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Related_distributions) random variable has distribution $\mathsf{Chiesq}(2).$ Look at the link under 'related distributions'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To formalize this problem, let the following be true:
$$\Delta x \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$
$$\Delta y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$
$$thr=3\sigma \ \therefore \ \Biggl\{ \begin{matrix} \mathbb P(-thr \le \Delta x \le thr)\approx 99.73\% \\
\mathbb P(-thr \le \Delta y \le thr)\approx 99.73\%\end{matrix}$$
$$r=\sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}$$

Then, as you said, random variable $r$ draws from a [Rayleigh Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) with a scale parameter of $\sigma$.  Now if you want to find the $F_r=99.73\%$ quantile of $r$, then you can just use the equation:

$$Q(F_r,\sigma)=\sigma \sqrt{-2 \ \mathrm{ln}(1-F_r)}$$
$$Q(0.9973,\sigma)=\sigma \sqrt{-2 \ \mathrm{ln}(1-0.9973)}=\frac{thr}{3} \sqrt{-2 \ \mathrm{ln}(1-0.9973)}$$